# Possible To Cancel The Task

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

To give you some background:

I have the user typing in a search action view.  After every change event of the text box I want to hit the web using a common API and display the returned data in a `listview` using the Endless Adapter.

Currently I retrieve data using `cacheInBackground()` and then I add them to the listview using `appendCachedData()`.

But if a user is typing fast I want to cancel the current running task so that a new one may start.  Currently the old task is running and `appendCachedData()` is putting old results in the `listview` because the API call could take a second or two to return data but the user is typing so fast.

What is the recommended action for doing this the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the recommended action for doing this the proper way?

IMHO, the "recommended action" is to not do this:

> After every change event of the text box I want to hit the web using a common API and display the returned data in a listview using the Endless Adapter

Either:

- Have all your data on the device, such that you can filter sans `EndlessAdapter, or
- Only do the network I/O and `EndlessAdapter` stuff on a positive user action (e.g., click search icon)